# Magento 2: Missing Product Images

Tags: magento, magento2

I am missing some of the product images from sample data on the front end.

I have already successfully ran:

```
 php -dmemory_limit=50G bin/magento sampledata:deploy 

 php -dmemory_limit=50G bin/magento setup:upgrade 

 php -dmemory_limit=50G bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
```

When I run:

```
    php -dmemory_limit=50G bin/magento catalog:images:resize
```

It goes through some files:

```
   1/801 [>-----------------------]   0% < 1 sec 82.0 MiB   | /m/b/mb01-blue   2/801 [>-----------------------]   0% 3 secs 82.0 MiB    | /m/b/mb04-blac  3/801 [>------------------]   0% 5 secs 84.0 MiB  | /m/b/mb04-black-0_alt1  5/801 [>-----------------]   0% 10 secs 84.0 MiB  | /m/b/mb03-black-0_alt1 15/801 [>-----------------]   1% 41 secs 84.0 MiB  | /w/b/wb06-red-0_alt1.j 21/801 [>-----------------]   2% 1 min 84.0 MiB    | /u/g/ug07-bk-0_alt1.jp 26/801 [>-----------------]   3% 1 min 84.0 MiB    | /l/u/luma-yoga-brick.j 27/801 [>-----------------]   3% 1 min 84.0 MiB    | /l/u/luma-foam-roller.
```

But eventually I get the following error:

```
    File '/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/Magento_2/pub/media/catalog/product/m/h/mh01-gray_main_1.jpg' does not exist.
```

It seems I am missing a lot of product images in:

/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/Magento_2/pub/media/catalog/product/

How do I go about fixing this?

Thanks!

Comment: The images are in my phpmyadmin database and it is not a file permissions error.  Any ideas on how to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Error is because image is not present in there respected folder, you can put images there(as it will be on server I think) or can remove from back-end(admin panel) by editing product one by one. You can also remove from DB but it is not the right way.